# I want design bunch of circles connecting with curved lines

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uibezierpath, curve

[Want to achieve something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n1UL.png) I have created circle using UIView but during creating quadCurve unable to find the control point for each line

```
func drawLineFromPoint(point1:CGPoint, point2:CGPoint) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: point1)
   // path.addLine(to: point2)
   path.flatness = 0.9
    path.addQuadCurve(to: point2, controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (point1.x+point2.x), y: (point1.y)))


let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

self.centerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: I don't see any quad curves in your image. There's only a big circle with a bunch of filled-in circles, right?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to draw each of the lines between the small circles. You can draw big circle first, then draw small circles *on that big circle*.

For example:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // change these as you wish
    let colors = [UIColor.red, .blue, .green, .red, .blue, .green, .red, .blue, .green, .red, .blue, .green]
    let bigCircleRect = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 16, dy: 16) // This is how big the big circle is compared to the view
    let bigCircle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bigCircleRect)
    bigCircle.lineWidth = 5
    UIColor.black.setStroke() // color of the big circle
    bigCircle.stroke()

    for (index, angle) in stride(from: -CGFloat.pi, to: .pi - .pi / 6, by: .pi / 6).enumerated() {
        let centerOfCircle = CGPoint(x: (bigCircleRect.width / 2) * cos(angle) + bounds.width / 2,
                                     y: (bigCircleRect.width / 2) * sin(angle) + bounds.width / 2)
        let smallCircleRect = CGRect(origin: centerOfCircle, size: .zero).insetBy(dx: -16, dy: -16) // size of small circle
        let smallCircle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: smallCircleRect)
        colors[index].setFill()
        smallCircle.fill()

    }
}
```

Output:

[image]